# ios10 calendar event times when changing time zones

Tags: calendar, ios, timezone

I am flying soon from New York to Hawaii. I've already set up events that will be happening in Hawaii using ios10 calendar, using Hawaii times. When I actually fly there, I want the calendar times to remain unchanged, as I entered them originally. How do I accomplish this on iphone 6plus?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the events using Hawaii times (ie you set your Hawaii noon meeting as an 8pm meeting while editing the calendar in New York), then there is no problem since when you set your device to Hawaii time all those events will be correctly displayed.

If you set up the events using NY times (you set your Hawaii noon meeting as a noon meeting while editing the calendar in New York), then you need to either edit all the Hawaii meetings or tell the calendar to ignore the time zone info and just display the events as entered by using "Time Zone Override" on the iPhone and setting the iPhone calendar to display events using the New York time zone.

To turn ***on*** **Time Zone Override**:

Go to Settings > Calendar

Move the switch to show green in order to turn on Time Zone Override.

> The Time Zone Override always shows event dates and times in the selected time zone.
>
> When off, events will display according to the time zone of your current location.

After turning ***on*** the Time Zone Override, you need to select the New York time zone.

[image: Time Zone Override settings calendar iOS]

Comment: Thank you @j-beda for adding clarification to the answer.  Cheers!

Comment: Turning on Time Zone Override also adds the option to change the time zone for a particular event when editing it (in the Calendar app).